# IOS error in design singleton instance AFNetworking 3

Tags: ios, singleton, afnetworking

Hi I'm building a singleton instance for `AFNetworking 3.x`

my ApiClient.h

```
@interface ApiClient : AFHTTPSessionManager
+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance;

-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url sessionConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration;
```

my ApiClient.m

```
+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance {
    static ApiClient *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SINGPOST_BASE_URL] sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

    });
return sharedInstance;
}
```

The problem is i cannot initiate an singleton instance

```
-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url sessionConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration {

    [super initWithBaseURL:url sessionConfiguration:url];
    return self;
}
```

I got 2 error as bellow pic [image]

Anyone know. What wrong with my singleton design? Any help is much appreciate! Thanks

PS: i have tried `initwithURL` only is not working without the session configuration

Update. There is an error typo. correct should be

```
-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url sessionConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url sessionConfiguration:configuration];

        if (self) {
//            self.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
//            self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
            [self setDataTaskWillCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse *(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask, NSCachedURLResponse *proposedResponse)
             {
                 NSHTTPURLResponse *resp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)proposedResponse.response;
                 NSMutableDictionary *newHeaders = [[resp allHeaderFields] mutableCopy];
                 if (newHeaders[@"Cache-Control"] == nil) {
                     newHeaders[@"Cache-Control"] = @"max-age=120, public";
                 }

                 //             NSHTTPURLResponse *response2 = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:resp.URL statusCode:resp.statusCode HTTPVersion:@"1.1" headerFields:newHeaders];

                 NSURLResponse *response2 = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:resp.URL statusCode:resp.statusCode HTTPVersion:nil headerFields:newHeaders];
                 NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse2 = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response2
                                                                                                 data:[proposedResponse data]
                                                                                             userInfo:[proposedResponse userInfo]
                                                                                        storagePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
                 return cachedResponse2;
             }];
        }

    return self;
}
```

It work fine now but whenever I try to call the viewcontroller again. the response serializer is not working properly (2nd call) have incorrect response while 1st call give correct response serializer). an app crash as a result

My strange response for 2nd call for viewcontroller 
[image]

Comment: Regarding your long hex string representation, `<7b22726f 6f74223a ...>`, that would appear to be a JSON response body (`{"root": ...}`). `AFHTTPSessionManager`'s default `AFJSONResponseSerializer` will convert that JSON into a dictionary for you. We can't advise you further without seeing how you produced that output. But this is all a completely different question from this, so post a new question on that topic, rather than editing this question further, including example of how you created the request and how you're letting AFNetworking parse that response for you.

Comment: Hi I have made another question regarding this problem. Can have a look, Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035982/cannot-make-singleton-for-json-and-xml-response-using-afnetworking-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When implementing `init` method, you want to say `self = ...`, e.g.

```
- (instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url sessionConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url sessionConfiguration:configuration];

    if (self) {
        // do additional configuration here
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: thanks there is an typo in my typing supper. It work fine now but whenever I try to call the viewcontroller again. the response serializer is not working properly (2nd call) have incorrect response while 1st call give correct response serializer). an app crash as a result

Comment: Hi I have made another question regarding this problem. Can have a look, Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035982/cannot-make-singleton-for-json-and-xml-response-using-afnetworking-3