# Cannot make singleton for JSON and XML response using AFNetworking 3

Tags: ios, json, xml, afnetworking, response

Hi I'm Making a singleton for networking for JSON and XML response

my ApiClient.h

```
+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance;

-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url sessionConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration;
```

My ApiClient.m

```
+ (ApiClient *)sharedInstance {
    static ApiClient *sharedInstance = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:SINGPOST_BASE_URL] sessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];

        [sharedInstance setDataTaskWillCacheResponseBlock:^NSCachedURLResponse *(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask, NSCachedURLResponse *proposedResponse)
         {
             NSHTTPURLResponse *resp = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)proposedResponse.response;
             NSMutableDictionary *newHeaders = [[resp allHeaderFields] mutableCopy];
             if (newHeaders[@"Cache-Control"] == nil) {
                 newHeaders[@"Cache-Control"] = @"max-age=120, public";
             }
             NSURLResponse *response2 = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:resp.URL statusCode:resp.statusCode HTTPVersion:nil headerFields:newHeaders];
             NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse2 = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response2
                                                                                             data:[proposedResponse data]
                                                                                         userInfo:[proposedResponse userInfo]
                                                                                    storagePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
             return cachedResponse2;
         }]; 
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
-(instancetype)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url sessionConfiguration:(NSURLSessionConfiguration *)configuration {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url sessionConfiguration:configuration];
        if (self) {
        }
    return self;
}
```

The problem is the singleton cannot handle both XML and JSON response. It can successfully parse the JSON and XML for 1 time. But when call again to parse again) (after successfully parse XML) result will not be parse properly (give hex string response)

My JSON block request

```
- (void)sendJSONRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
                success:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject))success
                failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer].acceptableContentTypes;

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error URL: %@",request.URL.absoluteString);
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            failure(error);
        } else {
            NSDictionary *jsonDict  = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
            success(response,jsonDict);
            NSLog(@"Success URL: %@",request.URL.absoluteString);
            NSLog(@"Success %@",jsonDict);
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];

}
```

My XML block request

```
- (void)sendXMLRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
               success:(void (^)(NSURLResponse *response, RXMLElement *responseObject))success
               failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    self.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    [self.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"application/xml"];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error URL: %@",request.URL.absoluteString);
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
            failure(error);
        } else {
            RXMLElement *rootXml = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLData:responseObject];
            success(response, rootXml);
            NSLog(@"Success URL: %@",request.URL.absoluteString);
            NSLog(@"Success %@",rootXml);

        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

My hex string fail resonse:
[image]

Anyway to make the singleton work properly or I need to make 2 singleton for JSON and XML response? Any help is much appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Simply showing us the hex string failure is not adequate, because that's just showing us the JSON body of the response. You should share the error messages, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is likely telling you that it was expecting a `Content-Type` of `application/xml`, and you may of had an `application/json`. It's hard to tell because you didn't share the full error, but it's likely something like that.

There are two logical approaches. Either:

1. Have single `AFHTTPSessionManager` accept both XML and JSON. So, with a `responseSerializer` of `AFHTTPResponseSerializer` and an `acceptableContentTypes` of both `application/xml` and `application/json` (or whatever specific `Content-Type` your two web services return), and then when you receive the `NSData` response object, either parse the XML or JSON as appropriate.
2. Have separate `AFHTTPSessionManager` objects, one for XML (with `responseSerializer` of `AFXMLResponseSerializer`) and one for JSON (with `responseSerializer` of `AFJSONResponseSerializer`). Note, if you do this, you don't have to adjust `acceptableContentTypes` at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I manage to use 1 singleton AFHTTPSessionManager. The trick is we need to set the correct XML or JSON request and response serializer: self.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]; for JSON and self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer]; for XML.  Do you know anyway we can use with possible 2 or 3 base URL?

Comment: Don't worry about the base URL. That's useful if the session is accessing a single server, but otherwise, use no base URL and provide a full URL to the request, and it takes the base URL out of the equation.

Comment: So what is the base URL do? I thought it uses to make connection faster or hold some info for identical connection?

Comment: The base URL is just a convenience so that you can reference end points in your web service without referencing the full URL. But, you can just as easily reference the full URLs (or write methods for building the URLs in your two web services respectively).

Comment: Thanks for all your clarification. one last question how do we maintain reliable connection to server during user usage (User can many request when they using app both POST and GET)? should we use cookies or other method

Comment: It's just a question of how the web service was written. It could be via cookies, or some web services end up providing some token that you you are provided after the server successful authenticates you and that you supply in subsequent requests. This is dictated by the authentication system employed by your web service.